# Postgresql - IN clause optimization for more than 3000 values

Tags: excel, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an application where the user will be uploading an excel file(.xlsx or .csv) with more than 10,000 rows with a single column "partId" containing the values to look for in database

I will be reading the excel values and store it in list object and pass the list as parameter to the Spring Boot JPA repository find method that builds IN clause query internally:

```
                // Read excel file
                stream = new   ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
                wb = WorkbookFactory.create(stream);
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(wb.getActiveSheetIndex());
                
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
                
                while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
                    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    vinList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }
                
                //JPA repository method that I used
                  findByPartIdInAndSecondaryId(List<String> partIds);
```

I read in many articles and experienced the same in above case that using IN query is inefficient for huge list of data.

How can I optimize the above scenario or write a new optimized query?

Also, please let me know if there is optimized way of reading an excel file than the above mentioned code snippet

It would be much helpful!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are examples on Stackoverflow using a `VALUES` join instead if `in`. Have you tried this?

Comment: @madflow, I have tried that. I would like to know if there are any other optimized way to do for a huge list of values

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Since I will be receiving the lists from User Interface via API, I am bound to move large lists between application and database. I don't know how to pass the list efficiently

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I am afraid that i am not clear with your statement :(. Could u please share any sample query ?

Answer (score 1):

If the list is truly huge, you will never be lightning fast.

I see several options:

1. Send a query with a large `IN` list, as you mention in your question.
2. Construct a statement that is a join with a large `VALUES` clause:

   ```
   SELECT ... FROM mytable
      JOIN (VALUES (42), (101), (43), ...) AS tmp(col)
         ON mytable.id = tmp.col;
   ```
3. Create a temporary table with the values and join with that:

   ```
   BEGIN;
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp(col bigint) ON COMMIT DROP;
   ```

   Then either

   ```
   COPY tmp FROM STDIN; -- if Spring supports COPY
   ```

   or

   ```
   INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (42), (101), (43), ...; -- if not
   ```

   Then

   ```
   ANALYZE tmp;  -- for good statistics
   SELECT ... FROM mytable
      JOIN tmp ON mytable.id = tmp.col;
   COMMIT;  -- drops the temporary table
   ```

Which of these is fastest is best determined by trial and error for your case; I don't think that it can be said that one of the methods will always beat the others.

Some considerations:

- Solutions 1. and 2. may result in very large statements, while solution 3. can be split in smaller chunks.
- Solution 3. will very likely be slower unless the list is truly large.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try all these ways and update the status of each solution.