# Postgresql : ERROR: in creating temp table with list object values

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin-4

I am writing a Postgresql function (using pgAdmin GUI) that will be invoked from my Spring Boot application with java list object as parameters

My actual requirement is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785993/postgresql-in-clause-optimization-for-more-than-3000-values/64790353#64790353) and with the suggestions to create a temp table with list values to optimize query, following is the Postgres function which I have tried by referring from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86724/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-using-values-in-postgresql):

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."getInventory"("vals1Arg" character varying[], "vals2Arg" character varying[])
    RETURNS "INVENTORY"
    LANGUAGE 'sql'      
    
AS 
$BODY$
 
// I assume the below two lines create two temp tables and populate the table 
   with my list object values
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 AS 
          SELECT * FROM VALUES(vals1Arg)

CREATE TEMP TABLE t2 AS 
          SELECT * FROM VALUES(vals2Arg)

SELECT * FROM "INVENTORY"
    where "COLUMN_1" in (select * from t1)
    and "COLUMN_2" in (Select * from t2);  
   
 $BODY$;
```

Following is the code snippet by how I am invoking postgres function

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select \"getInventory\" (:vals1Arg,:vals2Arg)")
    List<Inventory> getInventoryInfo(List<String> vals1Arg, List<String> vals2Arg);
```

As the list is going to be huge, I am creating a temporary table with values from the list object paramaters and use it in my select query

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: The body of your question doesn't mention the error in the title; when exactly are you getting this, and is this the **exact, full** wording you're seeing? Where does the temp table fit in, not shown in your query - is it just a detail of your wider problem that you should be ignoring until you get this part right?

Comment: When I chose my table name array in the return type drop down and tried to save the function in pgAdmin , i get the error

Comment: OK, so click [edit], delete all the information that's not relevant to that error (e.g. the discussion of temp tables, the Java code), and add instead the exact steps you took to get the error. Breaking the problem down and focussing on one part at a time is not only the best way of getting help, it's also one of the most important skills in programming.

Comment: Show the function definition and the calling SQL statement. Please not as image, but as formatted text.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe ,I have edited the question. Kindy take a look and guide me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. The syntax of the `CREATE TABLE ... AS` should be

   ```
   CREATE TABLE ... AS
      SELECT * FROM (VALUES (...)) AS alias;
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   CREATE TABLE ... AS
      SELECT * FROM VALUES (...);
   ```

   You need these parentheses and the alias.
2. The subselect in the query won't work, as it compares a `varchar` (`COLUMN_1`) with a `varchar[]` (the column of the temporary table).

   To make that work, you'd have to

   ```
   SELECT * FROM "INVENTORY"
      WHERE "COLUMN_1" = ANY (SELECT * FROM t1);
   ```

If you want to create temporary tables rather than using the array directly in the `SELECT`, you had better

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 AS
   SELECT * FROM unnest(vals1Arg) AS u(c);
CREATE TEMP TABLE t2 AS
   SELECT * FROM unnest(scomoIdList) AS u(c);

ANALYZE t1, t2;

RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "INVENTORY"
                JOIN t1 ON "INVENTORY"."COLUMN_1" = t1.c
                JOIN t2 ON "INVENTORY"."COLUMN_2" = t2.c;
```

This assumes that the lists don't contain duplicate entries.

Comment: I get syntax error "ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURN"". Any idea on how to resolve it?