# Postgresql - ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURN" SQL state: 42601

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am using Postgresql 9.6 and trying to create the following function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."getInventory"("vals1Arg" character varying[], "vals2Arg" character varying[])
    RETURNS json
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    
    
AS $BODY$

CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 AS 
          SELECT * FROM unnest(vals1Arg) AS u(c);

CREATE TEMP TABLE t2 AS 
          SELECT * FROM unnest(vals2Arg) AS u(c);

RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT * FROM "INVENTORY"
        JOIN t1 ON "COLUMN_1" = t1.c
        JOIN t2 ON "COLUMN_2" = t2.c;

$BODY$;
```

My actual requirement is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785993/postgresql-in-clause-optimization-for-more-than-3000-values/64790353#64790353) in separate post

I am getting the following syntax error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN"
LINE 12: RETURN QUERY 
         ^
SQL state: 42601
```

How do I resolve it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `return query` in a `language sql` function.

As you made your parameters case sensitive you also have to quote them when using them.

But as you are returning all rows from the `"INVENTORY"` table you also need to declare your function as `returns setof` "INVENTORY"`

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."getInventory"("vals1Arg" character varying[], "vals2Arg" character varying[])
    RETURNS setof "INVENTORY"
    LANGUAGE sql
AS 
$BODY$
  CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 AS 
          SELECT * FROM unnest("vals1Arg") AS u(c);

  CREATE TEMP TABLE t2 AS 
          SELECT * FROM unnest("vals2Arg") AS u(c);

  SELECT i.*
  FROM "INVENTORY" i
    JOIN t1 ON i."COLUMN_1" = t1.c
    JOIN t2 ON i."COLUMN_2" = t2.c;
$BODY$;
```

But the temp tables are unnecessary (and will slow down the query). You can use `unnest` directly in the query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."getInventory"("vals1Arg" character varying[], "vals2Arg" character varying[])
    RETURNS setof "INVENTORY"
    LANGUAGE sql
AS 
$BODY$
  SELECT i.*
  FROM "INVENTORY" i
    JOIN unnest("vals1Arg") AS t1(c) ON i."COLUMN_1" = t1.c
    JOIN unnest("vals2Arg") AS t2(c) ON i."COLUMN_2" = t2.c;
$BODY$;
```

---

But do you really want to *join* on the parameters? Maybe you intended an "IN" condition?

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."getInventory"("vals1Arg" character varying[], "vals2Arg" character varying[])
    RETURNS setof "INVENTORY"
    LANGUAGE sql
AS 
$BODY$
  SELECT i.*
  FROM "INVENTORY" i
  WHERE i."COLUMN_1" = any("vals1Arg")
    AND i."COLUMN_1" = any("vals2Arg");
$BODY$;
```

Comment: The size of my input arguments are going to be huge with length more than 3000 and I believe IN clause will slow down the query performance. Isnt it? That was the reason I tried to create a temp table with argument values and use JOIN instead

Comment: @code-geek I would expect the creation of the temp table (and inserting the rows) to be slower than joining to the unnest result. But you need to test that with your data and tablers.

Comment: I get 'org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function'. I am invoking postgres function from my spring boot application

Comment: Your function only has two parameters. It sounds as if your Java code doesn't pass two arrays, but a list of values - but that's an entirely different question.

Comment: Oops! My Java code passes a list object with more than 3000 values. Should I pass an array instead of List object?